# Vertical Rule in PGF Plottable

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, rules

I just learned to plot tables with pgfplottables and it feels very nice and smooth. Here is my Code example:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\pgfplotstableread{
    X          C1          C2          C3          C4
    $A$          1         1         1          1
    $B$          1         1         1          1
    $C$          1         1         1          1
    $D$          1         1         1          1
}\testdata


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every head row/.style={
    before row={\toprule 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{table}}\\            \cmidrule{2-3}},
    after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/X/.style={string type, column name={test},column type/.add={}{|}},
  columns/C1/.style={string type, column name={$a$}},
  columns/C2/.style={string type, column name={$b$}},
  columns/C3/.style={string type, column name={$c$}},
  columns/C4/.style={string type, column name={$d$}},
  columns={X, C1,C2,C3,C4},
]\testdata
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

My question is about the line

```
columns/X/.style={string type, column name={test},column type/.add={}{|}},
```

It gives me a line at the right place, but the rule breaks when it reaches the horizontal line right under "X a b c d" and it doesn't stop there but also implements a rule left to "table".

Is there a possibility to stop it right besides of $X$ without breaking when it passes the horizontal line?

Thank you!

Comment: Horizontal lines from the booktabs package are incompatible with vertical lines which is why you get gaps around the intersections.

Comment: Is there a possibility with pgfplottable to draw such vertical lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the output you're interested in, but by adding `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` you can shorten the vertical line. In the following example, I also replaced some of the `booktabs` lines with `\hline` and `\cline` in order to avoid gaps around the intersections of horizontal and vertical lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\pgfplotstableread{
    X          C1          C2          C3          C4
    $A$          1         1         1          1
    $B$          1         1         1          1
    $C$          1         1         1          1
    $D$          1         1         1          1
}\testdata


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  every head row/.style={
    before row={\toprule 
       \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{table}}\\            \cline{2-3}},
    after row=\hline},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/X/.style={string type, column name={test},column type/.add={}{|}},
  columns/C1/.style={string type, column name={$a$}},
  columns/C2/.style={string type, column name={$b$}},
  columns/C3/.style={string type, column name={$c$}},
  columns/C4/.style={string type, column name={$d$}},
  columns={X, C1,C2,C3,C4},
]\testdata
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Was struggling with multicolumn. Thats very nice, ty!